# Mutagen raise error while trying to read m4b file

Tags: python, mutagen

this is my first post here on SO. I am trying to read a m4b file using Mutagen on Python 3. Here is the code I am using.

```
for file in os.listdir(workingdir):
    if file.endswith('.m4b'):
      workingdirectory = 'my/directory/'
      commandtoexecute = ""
      metadata = MP4(file)
      print('read')
      xa9ART1 = metadata['\xa9ART']
      xa9nam1 = metadata['\xa9nam']
      xa9alb1 = metadata['\xa9alb']
```

and here is the error Im getting,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mutagen\mp4\_as_entry.py", line 183, in _parse_esds
    decSpecificInfo = ES_Descriptor.parse(fileobj)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mutagen\mp4\_as_entry.py", line 240, in parse
    instance = cls(fileobj, length)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mutagen\mp4\_as_entry.py", line 278, in __init__
    self.decConfigDescr = DecoderConfigDescriptor.parse(fileobj)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mutagen\mp4\_as_entry.py", line 240, in parse
    instance = cls(fileobj, length)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mutagen\mp4\_as_entry.py", line 315, in __init__
    self.decSpecificInfo = DecoderSpecificInfo.parse(fileobj)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mutagen\mp4\_as_entry.py", line 243, in parse
    raise DescriptorError("descriptor parsing read too much data")
mutagen.mp4._as_entry.DescriptorError: descriptor parsing read too much data

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mutagen\mp4\__init__.py", line 1014, in _parse_stsd
    entry = AudioSampleEntry(entry_atom, entry_fileobj)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mutagen\mp4\_as_entry.py", line 79, in __init__
    self._parse_esds(extra, fileobj)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mutagen\mp4\_as_entry.py", line 185, in _parse_esds
    raise ASEntryError(e)
mutagen.mp4._as_entry.ASEntryError: descriptor parsing read too much data

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\aud.py", line 944, in <module>
    my_function()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\aud.py", line 336, in create_rar
    metadata = MP4(file)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mutagen\_file.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.load(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mutagen\_util.py", line 140, in wrapper
    return func(self, h, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mutagen\mp4\__init__.py", line 1061, in load
    self.info.load(atoms, fileobj)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mutagen\_util.py", line 169, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mutagen\mp4\__init__.py", line 976, in load
    self._parse_stsd(atom, fileobj)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\mutagen\mp4\__init__.py", line 1016, in _parse_stsd
    raise MP4StreamInfoError(e)
mutagen.mp4.MP4StreamInfoError: descriptor parsing read too much data
```

I have tried it several times on several audios, but seems its stuck this way for me. Id be very glad to get help from here.

Thankyou.